# Communication between host Fragment and ViewPager's Fragment item

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there any standard pattern for communication between two fragments where **one fragment hosts another fragment**? This article [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) explains how to communicate between two (independent?) fragments where `Activity` is communication mediator. However, this "pattern" does not suit my case.

I have created fragment which contains `ViewPager`. **`ViewPager`'s items, fragments, produces some events which need to be processed in hosting fragment**. Since hosting fragment should be a standalone component, I would like to ommit `Activity` from the communication process.

What is the best place for registering of listeners in such case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our solution was to generalize the pattern you linked to from "communicate with my activity" to "communicate with my parent", which could be an Activity or another Fragment.

Instead of always expecting the Activity to implement an interface and casting it in `onAttach`, we have a utility method that looks for a valid callback for the current fragment and uses that at the point where we want to invoke the callback.

```
/**
 * @param fragment The fragment to get the listener for.
 * @param listenerClass The class of the listener to get.
 * @param <T> Type of the listener to get.
 * @return A listener object for the given fragment, cast from the owning parent fragment or
 * Activity, or null if neither is a listener.
 */
@Nullable
public static <T> T getListener(@NonNull Fragment fragment, @NonNull Class<T> listenerClass) {
    T listener = null;
    if (listenerClass.isInstance(fragment.getParentFragment())) {
        listener = listenerClass.cast(fragment.getParentFragment());
    }
    else if (listenerClass.isInstance(fragment.getActivity())) {
        listener = listenerClass.cast(fragment.getActivity());
    }

    return listener;
}
```

This says: given some fragment and an interface callback type, does my owning fragment implement that interface? If so use that. If not, does my Activity implement the interface? If so, use that. Essentially, we walk up the hierarchy looking for a handler.

So in your child fragment:

```
private void invokeListener() {
    Listener listener = getListener(this, Listener.class);
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onThingHappened();
    }
}
```

Then in your parent fragment:

```
public class ParentFragment extends Fragment implements Listener {
    @Override
    public void onThingHappened() {
        // Handle view pager fragment event
    }
}
```

If you later create an instance of the child and add it to an Activity, just have that Activity implements the callback, and it just works™.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect solution!